# Checking for common data inside an array of objects using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My mongoose Scheme is as follows

```
Project: {
    name: String,
    stat: Number,
    users: [
        {user_id: String}
    ]
}
```

So each project contains multiple users. I am provided with two user ids and I need to find documents which contain both of those ids. Tried using elemmatch but can't figure out correct syntax. Please suggest ways to find documents like these.

This is the code I tried

```
    Project.find({ 
    users: { 
       $elemMatch: { id: req.query.id1 },
       $elemMatch: { id: req.query.id2 } 
    }
 })
```

but this returns all project which contains any one of the ids, not both.

Comment: Can you add the code which you tried also. So that anyone could help here.

Answer (score 0):

So my original code was OK, it was not running due to some minor errors in other areas.

```
 Project.find({ 
    users: { 
        $elemMatch: { id: req.query.id1 },
        $elemMatch: { id: req.query.id2 } 
    }
 })
```

This is the code. I'll keep it here in case someone faces the same problem